# What does "Non Non Biyori" mean?

Tags: non-non-biyori

*Non Non Biyori* is a Japanese manga series written and illustrated by Atto. The series is still ongoing until this day, it has anime adaption in 2013 and 2015. After maybe 7 years later since 2013, i don't understand what does *Non Non Biyori* mean. I have read all the 10 volumes but still didn't understand what does the title mean or ever explained.

Was it the only author know what the meaning of Non Non Biyori ? Or it's just some random word with no meaning at all ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there's no official statement from the author, it's possibly **a combination of [*nonbiri*](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%82%93%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8A) (のんびり, carefree) and [*hiyori**](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%97%A5%E5%92%8C) (ひより, 日和, fine weather)**, which can be interpreted as **"fine weather (or fine days) to be carefree."**

This is strengthened by the fact that:

1. Outside of the manga/anime, there was also 「**のんびり**くえすと！」(***Nonbiri** Quest!*) radio corner
2. The ending theme was 「のんのん**日和**」 ("*Non Non **Biyori***"; here, *hiyori* is read as *biyori* due to [*rendaku*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku)/sequential voicing)

---

From the lyric of the ending theme,

> のんびりと歌うから　のんきな風が吹いた
>
> *nonbiri to utau kara　nonki na kaze ga fuita*

it might even imply that *Non Non Biyori* is a combination of [***non**ki*](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9A%A2%E6%B0%97) (easygoing), ***non**biri*, and ***(h/b)iyori***.